# Speed of calling a function Delphi vs C++

Tags: c++, performance, delphi, function-call

I'm translating the C code from the handmadehero.org project to Delphi code. I ran into a performance issue on a specific piece:

Original:

```
inline real32
Win32GetSecondsElapsed(LARGE_INTEGER Start, LARGE_INTEGER End)
{
    real32 Result = ((real32)(End.QuadPart - Start.QuadPart) /
                     (real32)GlobalPerfCountFrequency);
    return(Result);
}
```

My version:

```
function Win32GetSecondsElapsed(Start, &End : LARGE_INTEGER): real32; inline;
begin
 Result := (&End.QuadPart - Start.QuadPart) / GlobalPerfCountFrequency;
end;
```

After calling the sleep function there is this code to make sure that we hit the target frame rate:

```
SleepMilliSeconds = <some code that calcs how long to wait to hit target frame rate>
Sleep(SleepMilliSeconds);
real32 TestSecondsElapsedForFrame = Win32GetSecondsElapsed(LastCounter, Win32GetWallClock());
Assert(TestSecondsElapsedForFrame < TargetSecondsPerFrame);
```

If I use the same code (Only that it's the Delphi version), I get an assert error.

If I change the code to this:

```
TestSecondsElapsedForFrame := ((LastCounter.QuadPart - Win32GetWallClock().QuadPart) / GlobalPerfCountFrequency);
Assert(TestSecondsElapsedForFrame < TargetSecondsPerFrame);
```

The error goes away, so the call to the function in Delphi takes long enough to push me over the time allowed for the sleep to complete.
Does anyone know how I can fix this? 
I have tried changing the parameters in the Win32GetSecondsElapsed to be passed as pointers, but it did not help. 
I thought it may be because it's being passed by value and a copy needs to be made, but that is not it.
I think that the 'inline' directive is not taking effect.

I believe it should be possible for a Delphi application to be just as fast as a C application.

Comment: Calling a function should not take that much time, but presumably something goes wrong in this particular case. You'd have to inspect the generated code to determine what/why.

Comment: Note that "calling a function" in this case does not even matter. Since the "endtime" is taken as an argument in both cases!

Comment: I do not think it is wise to sleep in a game application. Each time the app comes to the point calculating/painting the next frame it should calculate how many frames should have been calculated since last call. Then calculate all of them and only paint the last one. Sometimes it is just a NOP call, sometimes you have to calculate some frames, depending of the current system state.

Comment: Even on a system with a slow GPU you will not really get out of time sync and feels more naturally for the eyes/brain.

Comment: I'm not designing how the code works, I'm just translating it.
If you want to discuss the reasons for how the code works, feel free to visit handmadehero.org. Casey Muratori will be happy to address your concerns as this code is all for educational purposes.

Comment: Whenever you're unsure of what the compiler generates, have a look at the assembly code that got generated. You can easily do it with most debuggers, included that in Delphi.
Both C/C++ and Delphi should generate very similar CPU code for a given calling convention, but depending on the type of parameters, there could be some differences, especially when code optimization/inlining is enabled, or other features like the /GS switch in VC++

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This function call is not causing any performance problems - the problems are in a completely different part of the code.

You're passing `Win32GetWallClock()` as `End`, and `LastCounter` as `Start`, so the function correctly computes

```
Win32GetWallClock().QuadPart - LastCounter.QuadPart
```

but the inline version computes

```
LastCounter.QuadPart - Win32GetWallClock().QuadPart
```

which is zero or negative.

Comment: I think I see what you are saying, I will check it out right away and report back.

Comment: I fixed this now and even the inline code now causes the assert error, so you are correct that it is not the function call that causes the problem.